# How to get real world coordinates from mod_tile and instruments for drawing routes on a map

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to create a small application for creating routes on a map. The result i want to get is a vector of points (longitude, latitude).
I found mod_tile project from osm (https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile) which allows to get tiles from tile server then render and draw them to a user using renderd tool.

But now i have a question: how can i draw a route (for example by clicking on a certain points) and then somehow get the real world coordinates (longitude, latitude) from that?

Or are there any other variants for tile rendering engine and etc.